# Yellow/Brownish bottom leaves in Cycas revoluta

Tags: diseases

I have a Cycas revoluta with bottom leaves with yellow/brown spots. I guess it's probably related with overwatering. However, the pattern that I saw in internet pictures was a bit different. So, it may be a disease. Any thoughts?

[image]